# PHP echo memory by process ID

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I have looked around and have learned that I can use the following to grab the CPU and Memory data for a specific PID:

```
echo shell_exec('ps -p 22583 -o "pcpu,pmem" | tail -n +2');
```

I type without the| `tail -n +2` I get the following:

```
%CPU %MEM
```

For some reason It will not return the actual values..

Can someone help me resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Do you know what `tail` does? If not, read the manual. 2) You already know how to grab the data, so what is the purpose of the question?

Comment: So you copy and paste code, it didn't work, so you posted to stackoverflow.com. I guess that is "programming" these days. Have you tried anything? Do you even understand that command line you're executing?

Comment: I have been playing with it but have been unsuccessful. I have done my looking around to get an understanding of how the command works. Some assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: [`tail`](http://www.linfo.org/tail.html) - You gotta be at least trying to pay attention. Welcome to SO. `:)`

Comment: Also see [`ps`](http://www.linfo.org/ps.html). And [piped or `|`](http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html).

Comment: I have managed to get php to print out the the ps command with -ef and -l but when I specify a specific PID it doesn’t show any values. What am I missing? =/

Comment: @AndrewZak Maybe that PID isn't running anymore? You should first get it working by reading the entire output of `ps`. Then `tail` or `grep` (or `sed` or `awk`) your way to the specific pieces of data you want.

Comment: The PID is still running. When I run the PS command through terminal it works fine. For some reason when I use the same command in php using shell_exec it does not list any results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried aux structure?

```
ps aux | grep 'process'
```